# mysql number literal in select statement

Tags: mysql, numbers, literals

Hi all(Note that I have similar topics with different questions),

I'm learning MySQL. I came across some multiple-choice questions.
If I doubted what the answer was or was not convinced it's correct I started searching google, stackoverflow and the mysql site.
However for some I still couldn't confirm what the correct answer was.

Question:

```
SELECT 'Student Name:' || Stud_Name FROM Students WHERE Stud_ID = 50;
```

Which of the following will be treated as a number literal in the SELECT statement?

Answers:
A. 50
B. Stud_ID
C. Student Name
D. ||

Proposed answer: D.
My answer would be A. As it's a number and it is a literal.
The double pipes concat values if PIPES_AS_CONCAT is set in SQL mode.
Otherwise it is a logical `OR`.
Is there something I overlook?

If you have any remark about this question/answer or for any of my remarks I'm happy to hear it!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Man,this site is quick becoming a check my homework thing.

Comment: Your reply is certainly a way of quick post count wins here. A quick check it ain't for me though. I learned it. I thought about it and searched to answer this question. I just don't have the confidence if it's me that's wrong or the question (as some have proven for my other questions)

Answer (score 0):

The answer "A" is clearly the correct answer.  You can read about number literals in the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/number-literals.html):

> 9.1.2. Number Literals
>
> Integers are represented as a sequence of digits. Floats use “.” as a decimal separator. Either type of number
>   may be preceded by “-” or “+” to indicate a negative or positive
>   value, respectively

Comment: Thank you for confirming and putting some reference !